# Error: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. when trying to launch app

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle, launch

The error happend after upgrading flutter to latest version `2.5.0` along side all of my packages and `gradle` to a newer version

full error message:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to find Build Tools revision 29.0.2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

`gradle` dependencies in app level:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0'
```

`gradle` dependencies in project level:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
```

I have also made sure that my emulator is connected to internet and that I have accepted android sdk license

Answer (score 2, accepted):

turns out the error was because my java version `jdk` was old and the issue was fixed by upgrading it to Java 13